# SignalR hub cannot call client: Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Tests.Server.Hubs.TypedClient does not have an implementation

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a simple SignalR hub class like this:

```
public class FooHub : Hub<IBar>
{
    public async Task Hello(string text)
    {
        await this.Clients.Caller.SaySomething (text);
    }
}
```

Basically, when the client calls `Hello` on the server, this will call back into the client's `SaySomething` function, which is declared on interface `IBar`:

```
public interface IBar
{
    Task OrderBeverage();
    Task SaySomething(string text);
}
```

This works fine with the magic of SignalR. Basically, the `Caller` propery above returns an instance of a dynamically generated proxy, which implements `IBar`.

However, if I rewrite `IBar` by applying the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), like this:

```
public interface IBar : IOrder, ISmallTalk
{
}

public interface IOrder
{
    Task OrderBeverage();
}

public interface ISmallTalk
{
    Task SaySomething(string text);
}
```

which should be functionally identical, I get a crash as soon as I try to call into the `Caller` returned `IBar` proxy, with following exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Method 'SaySometing' in type 'IBar' from assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Tests.Server.Hubs.TypedClient, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

It took me quite some time to figure out that I had to put all methods into `IBar` directly, for SignalR's `Hub<T>` implementation to work properly.

Is this by design? Did I miss something?

Comment: not sure really, but your interface has `SaySomething` misspelled.

Comment: @Jonesy - thanks, but that was just a typo in my question. The real code is quite different but boils down to this example.